# Definition of a function of sets

Tags: functions

Suppose I have two sets of variables: $S_1 = \{X_1,X_2,\dots\}$ and $S_2 = \{Y_1,Y_2,\dots\}$. I want to define a function $f$ that takes all variables in $S_1$ and $S_2$ as parameters: $$f(X_1,X_2,\dots,Y_1,Y_2,\dots) \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$

My question is if it is also mathematically correct to write the function $f$ above as following:
$$f(S_1,S_2) \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$
If not, how I should correctly write such a function.

I'm sorry for asking such a simple question. I'm a student in Computer Science who has not touched math for a long time.

Comment: There is no distinction between e.g.: $f(\{1,2\},\{8\})$ and $f(\{2,1\},\{8\})$. This because $\{1,2\}=\{2,1\}$. So the distinction between $f(1,2,8)$ and $f(2,1,8)$ gets lost this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or maybe you want not sets but sequences of variables (where order matters).
$$
S_1 = (X_1, X_2, \dots),\qquad S_2 = (Y_1, Y_2, \dots)
$$
Then it will be OK to write $f(S_1, S_2)$ to abbreviate
$f(X_1, X_2, \dots; Y_1, Y_2, \dots)$.